# How to stream asynchronous string from server

Tags: deno

I'm trying to stream the `html` response in Deno but can't quite figure it out.

Doing it from a Service Worker on the front end looks like this:

```js
async function streamResponse(html: {start: (s: string) => Promise<void>}) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder()
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller : ReadableStreamDefaultController<any>) {
            const send = (item: string) => controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(item))
            await html.start(send)
            controller.close()
        }
    })

    return new Response(stream, { headers: { "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" }})
}
```

When I do something similar to that in `Deno` (`req.respond({body: stream, headers})`) it says that the body can't be of the type `ReadableStream`. I know there is some way to do this. I just can't figure it out. What am I missing? I looked in multiple places trying to understand how it is done but I haven't found any good example yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to use `Deno.Buffer` as the writer and then bring in `BufReader` to wrap the writer.

```js
import { BufReader } from "https://deno.land/std@0.79.0/io/bufio.ts"
import { ServerRequest } from "https://deno.land/std@0.79.0/http/server.ts"
import { HTML } from "./html.ts"

var headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "text/html"
})

const encoder = new TextEncoder()

export async function toHTML(req: ServerRequest, html: Promise<HTML>) {
    var buffer = new Deno.Buffer()
    var body = new BufReader(buffer)

    var h = await html
    req.respond({body, headers})
    await h.start((item: string) => buffer.write(encoder.encode(item)))
}
```